# How can we generate CSS for a slide in a presentation (PPTX) using Python/.NET?

Tags: python, .net, reactjs, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to make an editor and need to parse slide content into an HTML canvas and I am unable to extract CSS for the same.

Comment: Exactly what CSS are you hoping to extract? PowerPoint files are not HTML and contain no CSS files.

Comment: I am making an editor, where I can upload a ppt file and edit it just like google slides/ zoho show. In order to display the content of the slide, I need to prepare an HTML canvas where I need CSS to position the items of the PPT so that it looks similar to the original slide.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to extract and parse the XML for each slide (and master/layout) and convert the internal coordinate system to HTML/CSS yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPoint files are OOXML. Styles are saved in several places. *slideMaster1.xml* contains **titleStyle**, **bodyStyle** and **otherStyle** for titles, placeholders and tables, respectively.

If layouts and/or slides have had their outline list levels modified instead of inheriting them from the slide master, then there will be **lstStyle** overrides in them.

Default text box styling is most often found in *theme1.xml* in the **txDef** section of **objectDefaults**. This section also stores the default line and default autoshape settings. More rarely, text box styling can be stored in the **defaultTextStyle** section of *presentation.xml*.

Finally, if the notes master outline levels have been modified, *notesMaster1.xml* will contains a **notesStyle** section.

Fortunately, all style sections have an identical syntax. Here's my article on otherStyle that explains some of the structure: [Default Table Text](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/03/xml-hacking-default-table-text/)